# Azure DevOps yaml pipeline Macro Syntax Macro Syntax variable from variable group default value

Tags: azure-devops

if I have steps

```yaml
steps:
      - bash: |
        echo "versionType: $(versionType)"
```

and I define `versionType` in a variable group which is used by pipeline all works fine. If it is not defined it blows up. I'd like to use a default value in case if not defined to avoid blow up. How I can specify default value if not defined? I tried `${{ coalesce(variables.versionType,someType)}}` and I always get someType.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately variables do not directly allow for a default value the way a parameter would. If possible, consider using a parameter in which case you can use something like this:

```
parameters:
- name: versionType
  type: string
  default: ''
```

Otherwise, if you need it to be a variable group, you can perform a check before that step something like this:

```
- ${{ if not(eq(variables['versionType'], '')) }}:
  - bash: |
    echo "versionType: $(versionType)"
```

Comment: Ryan, many thanks. But I need default value to use further. The proposed  if block would be not nice. I have a powershell script which will be using that value. I need initialise powershell variable with some value. The powershell relatively big so I can't repeat it twice and make 2 versions, the situation is complicated as it is in the template which has only steps which are referenced. So I can't add a block varaibles: before steps.

Comment: In ADO, Variable Groups have variables with static data. Can you add the 'versionType' variable to the other group it doesn't currently exist in and give it the default value you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

We have no method to specify a default value for undefined variables on Azure DevOps.

In Azure Pipelines, if you want to use a variable, you should define it with a specified value at first. You can define the variable directly on the current pipeline, in a variable group or in the variable template.

You also can use the logging command "[**`SetVariable`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable)" to define a new variable or update the existing variable with the specified value in a running job. Then in the subsequent tasks in the job you can use the variable with the new value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not a great design

Comment: Hi @AlexK,

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend that you can report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion).
That will make it possible for you to interact with the appropriate engineering team, and make it more convenient for the engineering team to collect and categorize your suggestions.